# 'Lost' follow along resources?

Tags: lost

Going through the entire series 'Lost' again with my brother who hasn't seen it.  One of the biggest aspects to the show was the week to week community and analysis of each episode.

I was wondering if there's any online resource we can refer to in a 'follow along' type of way to somewhat recreate that.

For example, if we watch S01E10, after watching it we'd like to go and read a bit of analysis for that episode, without spoilers.  Then do that for each episode as we go along.

Or if you have a better idea of how to enhance our experience, let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think *Lostpedia* is probably your best bet (as long as you stick to the episode descriptions without clicking on any of the links).

For example, can read the summary of episode 10 here:
http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Raised_by_Another